# Replacement for ‘at the example of ’

Tags: phrases, phrase-requests, technical

I’m currently searching for the title of my research thesis and I can’t find a good phrase.

I did a “Systematic Analysis of fruit growth” in a generic way and additionally applied the analysis to apples.

Regarding the content I thought of the following title:

- “Systematic Analysis of the fruit growth at the example of apples”
- “Systematic Analysis of the fruit growth exemplify by apples”

Both sound awkward and might even be not correct (they sound incorrect to me)

I came up with the following other possibilities:

- “Systematic Analysis of the fruit growth demonstrated on apples”
- “Systematic Analysis of the fruit growth taking the example of apples”
- “Systematic Analysis of the fruit growth applied on apples”
- “Systematic Analysis of the fruit growth using apples as a case study”
- “Systematic Analysis of the fruit growth demonstrated on apples as a case study”

None of these really fits what I wanted to say. I would go for the first one, but I’m not sure whether “demonstrate” might be to informal and one might think of a “demonstration” (show on a stage).

Is there another correct phrase for “at the example of ”?

Comment: Is it an actual fruit growth you're studying - like a wart or a tumour - or are you studying the way in which fruit grows? If the latter, don't use "the" (or "a").

Comment: Neither, its just an example, the topic is more complicated and contains many words not everybody might understand, so I replaced the words. The `the` does not matter, but thanks for the hint.

Comment: Ah. The words might actually matter. For instance, you can *apply* gene splicing *to* apples, *apply* pest spray *on* apples, demonstrate fruit growth *with* apples... it depends whether the apples intrinsically hold an example of the phenomenon you're studying, or are an example subject to which you apply something to study the phenomenon, etc.

Comment: I think I choose the words correctly, I developed a analysis (which could be applied on many different fruits) and applied it (or used it) on one of the fruits (apple).

Comment: How important are the apples?  "Systematic Analysis of fruit growth: a case study" is a pattern I see a lot.

Comment: You have some English usage problems in your question. I'm hesitant to edit your question since it might change its intent, but I will do so to help you with the correct forms. So let me just point out that " at the example of apples" should be "by" or "through" the example of apples; "exemplify by apples" should be "exemplified by apples", "applied on apples" should be "applied to apples".

Comment: Alas! I do not have edit privileges.

Comment: Edit Prileges: A Case Study

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Systematic analysis of fruit growth exemplified by apples

sounds good.

Comment: Or *Systematic analysis of fruit growth in apples*— although I suppose that could be misconstrued as limiting the treatment solely to apples.

Answer (score 11):

Though @Will came up with the right word to directly replace "at the example of", I like your "Systematic Analysis of fruit growth using apples **as a case study**" (minus the "the"), since it says exactly what it is, a case study (assuming you actually did one).

Comment: I like this one, except for the extra 'the'.

Comment: Woah, didn't notice that...will edit.

Answer (score 4):

Two options using *case study*, depending on the primary focus:

> Systematic Analysis of fruit growth: a case study
>
> Apples: a case study of systemic analysis of fruit growth

I'm not an academic, but the papers I encounter at technical conferences often use "case study" and rarely use "example".

Comment: +1 for the first suggestion. The second suggestion seems awkward to me , because it's probably not a case study *of* systematic analysis, but rather, a case study *exemplifying* systematic analysis. (But I could be wrong.)

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn’t say “at the example of” – don’t use “at”. Maybe “using the example of”. But in any case, for a title this is rather long-winded and awkward, even for the normally long-winded and awkward titles of academic papers.

Without knowing anything about your paper, I’d be more likely to choose something like, “Systematic Analysis of Fruit Growth: A Case Study on Apples”.

I’m hard-pressed to state a rule to justify this, but I think the word “example” is rarely appropriate in a title in the way you’re trying to use it. Maybe a case like, “Economic Devastation of Civil War: The Liberian Example”. But if you’re creating the example, then you tend to call it a “case study”. And even in my Liberian example, it would be at least as good to say, “Economic Devastation of Civil War: A Liberian Case Study”.

For a non-title, i.e. text within the body of a discussion, I might say something like, “We performed a systematic analysis of fruit growth using apples as an example.”